# Conditional panel in Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I have a question about conditional panel in shiny dashboard. Is there a possibility to make conditional panel with condition on `menuItem` in `sidebarMenu`? My goal is to obtain an additional `selectInput` after click on menu tab `title2` (but it should stay invisible for `title1` tab).

I am doing something like follows

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("tab title1", tabName = "name1", icon = icon("th")),
            menuItem("tab title2", tabName =  "name2", icon = icon("th"))
         ),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.tabName == 'name2'",
            selectInput("period", "Period:", 
                        choices = list("Years" = 1, "Months" = 2))
        )
        ),
    dashboardBody())
```

In standard `shiny` it could be done by add `, value=1` to tab but here it doesn't work. Does anyone know any solution?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding an extra argument `id` to `sidebarMenu` solves the problem.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Basic Dashboard"),
dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="menu1",
        menuItem("tab title1", tabName = "name1", icon = icon("th")),
        menuItem("tab title2", tabName =  "name2", icon = icon("th"))
     ),
    conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.menu1 == 'name2'",
        selectInput("period", "Period:", 
                    choices = list("Years" = 1, "Months" = 2))
    )
    ),
dashboardBody())
```